# Create new \subsubsubsection in custom class file

Tags: table-of-contents, sectioning, sections-paragraphs, documentclass-writing

I've copied the default `article.cls` file and made some very minor alterations mainly to the `\listoftables` and `\listoffigures` titles, which is not connected to my question.

I'd like to add 1 extra level in between `\subsubsection` and `\paragraph`.  This new section would push down `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` down one level to make room for the new `\subsubsubsection` to be insert at level 4.

Microsoft Word comes with 9 headings which aren't inline headings, whilst I don't require that many at the moment, I do require the first 4 to not be inline headings and additional two headings as paragraph inline heading should be sufficient for my needs.

This section would appear fairly similar to `\subsubsection` in that it would be a heading on it's own line and not how the \paragraph command works with having the content on the same line as the heading.

I'm not using `\paragraph` or `\subparagraph` in my report for that reason. But am needing a **1.1.1.1 Section** in my report and on my contents page.

There is a solution on this site that looked like what I was trying to achieve, but I was unable to get it to work from within my custom class file.

Comment: just use `\paragraph` but style paragraph to be a display rather than a run-in header (which is just one line of code) That is far easier than implementing a whole new section level

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I understand it is easier, but your answer doesn't answer my question, you've just given me an alternative solution.

I' wanting to keep the `\paragraph` as they are as whilst I am not needing them for the report I am writing at the moment, what if I did want to use them later on.  I wouldn't be able to as I have changed them in the class file.

I would like to add in an extra level between `\subsubsection` and `\paragraph`.

If it was easy then everyone would be doing it, I am still learning LaTeX have only been using it a week, having just been introduced to it!

Comment: No really you can't have two section commands both at level 4 (tables of contents and other things) really assume that ther is a strict order to the heading commands so if you insert a new command at level 4 (after subsubsection) you would need to redefine \paragraph to be level 5 and subparagraph to be level 6

Comment: so to my answer you can add `\let\subsubsubsection\paragraph \let\paragraph\subparagraph \let\subparagraph\undefined` then you could use your preferred name

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes that is what I was wanting to do, as I mentioned I wanted to insert a new section inbetween the `\subsubsection` and `\paragraph` so `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` would be pushed down one level.

Comment: but you say you have been using latex a week, I've been using it 30 years and have never needed that are you sure that redefining all section levels rather than using the 5 predefined section levels is really the most easily maintainable solution?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Unfortunately I do require it yes, as the report I am working on has been written in microsoft word, and there is a total of 9 headings available.  I would like to learn how to create my own `\subsubsubsection`, I am creating my own `document-class` and did use that tag for my question.  Just to clarify only the first four are in use for the report I am making in LaTeX.

Comment: I might add something later (not tonight packing up now:-) but I'd note that your question is misleading and I think my existing answer is a better answer for the question as asked (where you say that you don't use `\paragraph` as it is an inline heading, which is a common misconception and the main thing that I wanted to answer) the question makes no mention of needing 9 heading levels (which changes things completely)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh right I see, I didn't intentionally mean to mislead with the question. I've editted my question.  I would also need the solution to work in my custom class file as I have already found that `\makeatletter` and `\makeatother` can't be used there.

Comment: @ is a letter in class files anyway so just don't use makeatletter makeatother as they are implicitly applied around the whole code

Comment: Are you going to use the `hyperref` package?

Comment: @GuM erm I am not sure, does that change things if so?

Comment: Well, you have to notify `hyperref` of the changes you make to the levels of the various sectioning commands.  If you introduce a new level between `\subsubsection` and `\paragraph`, the package should be informed…

Comment: @GuM do you know how that is done?

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Just use `\paragraph` but style paragraph to be a display rather than a run-in header. That is far easier than implementing a whole new section level:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
%same as \subsubsection but level 4
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{4}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
% number \paragraph
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{zzz}
\subsection{zzz}
\subsubsection{zzz}
\paragraph{zzz}
aaa
\end{document}
```